# PHP Pagination Function Not Displaying Properly

Tags: php, function, hyperlink, pagination

I have this function I have for pagination, and it's set to only show you 10 pages at a time in the links. So say there are 11 pages, then the links look like

1 | **2** | **3** | **4** | **5** | **6** | **7** | **8** | **9** | **10** | **Next »** | **Last »**

And then on the 11 page it will look like

**« First** | **« Prev** | 11

But, on the tenth page, this is what it looks like

**« First** | **« Prev** | **11** | **Next »** | **Last »**

Here's the PHP function I'm using (sorry, it's rather large)

```
function get_paging_link($sql, $itemPerPage = 10, $strGet = '') {
    global $db2;
    global $q;
    $result = $db2->GetDataTable($sql);
    $pagingLink = '';
    $totalResults = count($result);
    $totalPages = ceil($totalResults / $itemPerPage);
    $numLinks = 10;
    if ($totalPages > 1) {
        $self = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        if (isset($_POST['page']) && $_POST['page'] > 0) {
            $pageNumber = $_POST['page'];
        } else {
            $pageNumber = 1;
        }
        if ($pageNumber > 1) {
            $page = $pageNumber - 1;
            if ($page > 1) {
                $prev = " <a class=\"paginglink\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"refreshsearch('$q',$page);return false;\">&laquo; Prev <sp>|</sp></a> ";
            } else {
                $prev = " <a class=\"paginglink\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"refreshsearch('$q',$page);return false;\">&laquo; Prev <sp>|</sp></a> ";
            }
            $first = " <a class=\"paginglink\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"refreshsearch('$q',1);return false;\">&laquo; First <sp>|</sp></a> ";
        } else {
            $prev = '';
            $first = '';
        }
        if ($pageNumber < $totalPages) {
            $page = $pageNumber + 1;
            $next = " <a class=\"paginglink\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"refreshsearch('$q',$page);return false;\"><sp>|</sp> Next &raquo;</a> ";
            $last = " <a class=\"paginglink\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"refreshsearch('$q',$totalPages);return false;\"><sp>|</sp> Last &raquo;</a> ";
        } else {
            $next = '';
            $last = '';
        }
        $start = $pageNumber - ($pageNumber % $numLinks) + 1;
        $end = $start + $numLinks - 1;
        $end = min($totalPages, $end);
        $pagingLink = array();
        for ($page = $start; $page <= $end; $page++) {
            if ($page == $pageNumber) {
                $pagingLink[] = " $page ";
            } else {
                if ($page == 1) {
                    $pagingLink[] = " <a class=\"paginglink\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"refreshsearch('$q',1);return false;\">$page</a> ";
                } else {
                    $pagingLink[] = " <a class=\"paginglink\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"refreshsearch('$q',$page);return false;\">$page</a> ";
                }
            }
        }
        $pagingLink = implode(' <sp>|</sp> ', $pagingLink);
        $pagingLink = $first . $prev . $pagingLink . $next . $last;
    }
    return $pagingLink;
}
```

I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong with the math. I've played around with the adding and subtracting of 1's but to no avail. Thanks in advance! And sorry for the tall post

**EDIT:** To try to make the problem clearer, when I'm on every 10th page (10,20,30,...), that's when it shows the next set of ten links. It shows them a page to soon when on the 10th page.

**EDIT 2:** I replaced the block that contains the paging function (starting with `$start = $pageNumber - ($pageNumber % $numLinks) + 1;` and ending before `$pagingLink = implode(' <sp>|</sp> ', $pagingLink);`) with this:

```
$max_page_links = 10;
        if ($pageNumber > $max_page_links / 2) {
            if (ceil($totalResults / $itemPerPage) - $pageNumber < (($max_page_links / 2) + 1)) {
                $start_counter = $pageNumber - ($max_page_links - (ceil($totalResults / $itemPerPage) - $pageNumber)) + 1;
                $end_counter = ceil($totalResults / $itemPerPage);
            } else {
                $start_counter = $pageNumber - (($max_page_links / 2) - 1);
                $end_counter = $pageNumber + ($max_page_links / 2);
            }
        } else {
            $start_counter = 1;
            $end_counter = $max_page_links;
        }
        for ($i = $start_counter; $i <= $end_counter; $i++) {
            if ($i == $pageNumber) {
                $pagingLink[] = " $i ";
            } else {
                $pagingLink[] = " <a class=\"paginglink\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"refreshsearch('$q',$i);return false;\">$i</a> ";
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to debug this condition if ($pageNumber < $totalPages) see what $pageNumber and $totalPages contains when you click on page no 11

Comment: Those check out fine, but I'm pretty sure my problem lies within the bottom where it starts with `$start = $pageNumber - ($pageNumber % $numLinks) + 1;`

Answer (score 2):

You are right. Your equation:

```
$pageNumber - ($pageNumber % $numLinks) + 1 // This equates to 11 when pageNumber is 10
```

I use the following for pagination:

```
// set the limit of pictures, page number, and number of pages
// multiples of 4 unless you change column count below
$limit = $itemPerPage;
// figures number of pages needed
$numofpages = ceil($totalResults / $limit);

for($i = 1; $i <= $numofpages; $i++){
    if($i == $page){
        echo $i . " ";
    }else{
        echo "<a href='gallery.php?page=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a> ";
    }
}
```

The above For Loop can be changed to show only 10 with some modification.

```
for($i = 0; $i <= $numofpages; $i++){
    $pageNum = $page;
    $currentPageIndex = floor($pageNum/10); // Will return 1 for 11
    $pageIndex = ($currentPageIndex * 10) + 1);
    if($currentPageIndex > 0) {
        $pageIndex = ($currentPageIndex * 10) + 1);
        if($pageIndex == $page){
            $pagingLink[] = " $pageIndex ";
        } else {
            $pagingLink[] = " <a class=\"paginglink\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"refreshsearch('$q',$pageIndex);return false;\">$page</a> ";
        }
    } else {
        if($i == $page){
            $pagingLink[] = " $page ";
        } else {
            $pagingLink[] = " <a class=\"paginglink\" href=\"#\" onclick=\"refreshsearch('$q',$i);return false;\">$page</a> ";
        }
    }
}
```

*Have not tested modified code. May need some tweeking*

Comment: Not to be bashing or rude, but that code block did't work in the slightest. I also spent about 2 hours attempting to tweak it but I kept making things worse. Until somehow, I came up with this, which makes it work perfectly and even better than I had hoped it would work. I've updated my answer to show what the changes I made were.